# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Unable to give player custom potion with Harming 4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Holy Hand Grenade type of splash potion which has instant harming 4. I have

```
give @s minecraft:splash_potion{CustomPotionEffects:{id:7,Amplifier:3,ShowParticles:0},Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:multishot",lvl:1}],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch\",\"color\":\"gold\"}"}} 2
```

and I followed the wiki in adding the tags, but for some reason it doesn't even have harming, it only has uncraftable potion.

A) What am I doing wrong to not get the harming effect at all?

B) Is it possible to get harming 4? If it is, how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CustomPotionEffects` is a list, so everything in it has to be put into square brackets (`[]`).

And for some reason custom potion effects, as the only place in the game, require "`Id`" with a capital "I/i". Note that the non-capital "`id`" is indeed correct for the enchantments.

Putting these two corrections together, the correct command should be:

```
give @s minecraft:splash_potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:3,ShowParticles:0}],Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:multishot",lvl:1}],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch\",\"color\":\"gold\"}"}} 2
```

Source: I always start at "chunk format" as the central hub for everything, because I'm lazy, which directs me to "Player.dat#Item structure", specifically to [Potion effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Potion_Effects) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Player.dat_format&oldid=1365620#Potion_Effects)).

Comment: So the amplifier is the level, correct? So because strong_harming is Id 7 if I want strong_harming 3 I'd put the amplifier as 3?

Comment: Also, because CustomPotionEffects is a list, if I did multiple sets of curly braces in it separated with commas could I create a custom potion with multiple effects?

Comment: @Nik3141 Yes and yes.

Comment: Sorry, last question, I promise. I put `CustomPotionColor:[1,1,1]` in the nbt and it gave me the same potion as without it. I put it in a `tag:{}` tag (because the wiki says to) and it again gave me the same potion. I put it and `CustomPotionEffects:` inside the `tag:{}` tag and it broke and gave me an uncraftable one again (the wiki says CustomPotionEffects does go in tag so maybe it's outdated?). I replaced [] with {} and it broke it completely and the command wouldn't run. Where do I put the `CustomPotionColor:` tag (and how do I make it give me a gold color, if you know)?

Comment: It's on the same level as "`CustomPotionEffects`", as you can see in the tree view. The little "`I`" on the icon at the start of the explanation shows you that it's an integer, not a list of three numbers. So 1/256=0.390625% for R, G and B each would be hex 010101 and decimal 65793.